# placement new operator in c++ lang

Tags: c++

I tried a simple program to understand the placement new operator,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
        char *buf = new char[sizeof(string)];
        string *p = new (buf) string("hi");
        string *q = new string("bye");
        buf = (char*)"hello";
        cout << "buf :" << &buf << endl;
        cout << "p :" << p << endl;
        cout << "q :" << q << endl;
        cout << "buf :" << buf << endl;
        cout << "p :" << *p << endl;
        cout << "q :" << *q << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

How to print the address that buff is pointing to ?
&buff will give the address of the pointer buff and not the address it is pointing .

I wanted to check whether the buff and q are pointing to the same memory location.

Also if I comment, **buf = (char*)"hello";**

buff is giving a different address. Please help to understand.

Comment: cout << (void *) buf;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print addresses, cast to `void*`. For example:

```
cout << "buf :" << (void*)buf << endl;
```

If you just try to print a `char*`, the `char*` overload of `operator<<()` is used, which tries to print a C string, not an address.

Comment: Thanks, It worked for buff, P is printing the address and *p is printing the string. In C printf(%s,p) will print the string. But the address pointed to by the buff and P are different.

Comment: Placement new will give the already allocated memory(memory that is pointing to buff) to P. To check this I'm printed the address contained in buff and P. They both are different

Comment: @Angus You are assigning to `buf` before printing its address, therefore you get a different address. Comment out the assignment to `buf` and you should get the same address for `buf` and `p`.

Comment: Thanks Nikos. I could see the same address, that buf and p are poinitng to.

Answer (score 1):

On this line

```
char *buf = new char[sizeof(string)];
```

you ask the computer to set a place for the char `buf` but you don't asset any value to this so the output is the address of `buf`. On this line

```
buf = (char*)"hello";
```

you set the content of the memory reserved for `buf` to the string "hello" and that's why you don't see the address.

Answer (score 1):

A `std::string` is more than just a buffer. It has an internal buffer and you can access it by calling `c_str()`, as in:

```
cout << "p :" << (void*)p->c_str() << endl;
cout << "q :" << (void*)q->c_str() << endl;
```

That said, you are reassigning `buf` to a different memory location and I'm not sure you really know what that means. For example, your code does not delete the objects and frees the memory, at the end of your code you probably want something like

```
delete q;
p->~string();
delete[] buf; // this needs to be the original pointer returned by new, not the modified one in your code!
```

Comment: p->c_str() gives the value contained in the pointer. and &p->c_str() gives an error as lvalue required.

Comment: @Angus Duh! I meant to write something else, see my edited answer.